# How does ES6 function's default parameter return undefined, opposed to throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, ecmascript-6

```
var myFunc = function(x = getUndefined()){
    return x
};
function getUndefined(){
    return undefined
};
```

I want to know why this returns undefined instead of throwing some sort of error.  How does x know not to keep calling `getUndefined()`?

Comment: It's not throwing an error because it is valid syntax used properly. What exactly you find odd here?

Comment: Why would it keep calling `getUndefined()`? If no value is provided for a parameter, the expression of the default parameter is evaluated and passed into the function instead.

Comment: I understand the syntax is correct

Comment: So, what's the problem then? :-S

Comment: I thought for some reason this would cause an endless loop call to `getUndefined()`

Comment: If you want to make it endlessly loop, do `var myFunc = function(x = myFunc()){}; myFunc();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a sense of what is happening under the hood, you can look at how this code transpiles down to ES5:

```
"use strict";

var myFunc = function myFunc() {
    var x = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? getUndefined() : arguments[0];

    return x;
};
function getUndefined() {
    return undefined;
};
```

The function `getUndefined` is only called if there is no passed value for `x`.

While ES6 engines might not follow this exact strategy, it is most likely fairly similar.

Comment: In hindsight, I should of just went to the [Traceur Compiler](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#) and looked.